# Understanding numpy self-referencing assignment

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

Given a self-referencing assignment like this:

```
x = np.array(range(5))
y = x[:-1]
print(x, y)
y[0] = 9
print(x, y)
x[1:] = y
print(x, y)
```

I end up with the following output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4] [0 1 2 3]
[9 1 2 3 4] [9 1 2 3]
[9 9 1 2 3] [9 9 1 2]
```

Can someone explain what numpy is doing under the hood to avoid overwriting `y` before assigning its values to `x`? For example, if we replace the assignment `x[1:] = y` with a for loop, the final line of output is different:

```
x = np.array(range(5))
y = x[:-1]
print(x, y)
y[0] = 9
print(x, y)

for idx in range(1, len(x)):
    x[idx] = y[idx-1]
print(x,y)
```

```
[0 1 2 3 4] [0 1 2 3]
[9 1 2 3 4] [9 1 2 3]
[9 9 9 9 9] [9 9 9 9]
```

**Generally speaking**, can I rely on the observed behavior when changing the width of an memory-mapped ndarray? Or is it pointless if numpy is creating a copy of the view before assignment anyways?

Comment: Numpy operations are buffered, yes

Answer (score 0):

So you have a simple 1d array:

```
In [358]: x = np.array(range(5))
In [359]: x
Out[359]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
In [360]: x = np.arange(5)
In [361]: x
Out[361]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

`y` is a view - all but the last:

```
In [362]: y = x[:-1]
In [363]: y
Out[363]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
In [364]: y[0] = 9
In [365]: x
Out[365]: array([9, 1, 2, 3, 4])
```

modifying `y` changes `x` as well.

```
In [366]: x[1:]
Out[366]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])
In [367]: x[1:] = y
In [368]: x
Out[368]: array([9, 9, 1, 2, 3])
```

this assignment is buffered.  Details of that buffering is not generally documented, but the docs for functions like `np.add.at` hint at it.  While that explains the behavior that you see, I don't know if it's safe to assume it.  Adding a copy is cheap enough:

```
x[1:] = y.copy()
```

As illustrated with `add.at`, people usually are bothered by the buffering, at least in the case where some indicies are duplicated.  I can't think of a `.at` way of doing your iterative case.

---

There is a form of `view` copying that bites - for example trying to switch the rows of a 2d array:

```
In [392]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [393]: arr
Out[393]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
In [394]: arr[0],arr[1] = arr[1],arr[0]
In [395]: arr
Out[395]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Here `arr[0]` gets updated before `arr[1]`.  This kind of assignment works with lists, but because `arr[i]` is a `view` it fails with lists.

Advanced indexing gets around this.  The RHS is a copy, and thus isn't messed up during the assignment.

```
In [396]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [397]: arr[[0,1]] = arr[[1,0]]
In [398]: arr
Out[398]: 
array([[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

I don't know if it's possible to construct such an example with your 1d `x`.